# Swagger-ui-express module, instantiates only the last defined document

Tags: node.js, typescript, singleton, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a Typescripted nodejs server and i'm trying to define diffrent swagger paths for seperated controllers, but the swagger-ui-express module seems to only show the last defined doc in the specific route.

index.ts for X group of controllers

```
import express from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
const router = express.Router();
// import all bot routes
import { authRoute } from './auth';
import { botCrudRoute } from './bot-crud';
import { aiRoutes } from './ai';
import { categoryCrudRoute } from './categories-crud';

const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
import { botSwaggerDoc } from './swagger';

const swaggerDoc = botSwaggerDoc;

const swaggerUiOpts = {
    explorer: false
};

// Swagger setup
router.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve);
router.get('/api-docs', swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDoc, swaggerUiOpts));
```

index.ts for Y group of controllers

```
import express from 'express';
const router = express.Router();
// import all bot routes

const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
import { adminSwaggerDoc } from './swagger';

const swaggerDoc = adminSwaggerDoc;

const swaggerUiOpts = {
    explorer: false
};

// Swagger setup
router.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve);
router.get('/api-docs', swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDoc, swaggerUiOpts));

export const adminRoutes = router;
```

api.ts grouping all groups of controllers

```
'use strict';

import express from 'express';
import { Response, Request, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { adminRoutes } from './admin';
import { botRoutes } from './bot';
// import { onboardRoutes } from './onboard';

const router = express.Router();

// router.use('/onboard', onboardRoutes);
router.use('/bot', botRoutes);
router.use('/admin', adminRoutes);

export const apiRoutes = router;
```

server.ts

```
/**
 * Primary app routes.
 */
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

example of one of the swaggerDoc's

```
export const botSwaggerDoc = {
    'swagger': '2.0',
    'info': {
        'version': '1.0.0',
        'title': 'Cupo embed chat bot API',
        'license': {
            'name': 'Internal use only'
        }
```

the swagger-ui-express module only use the last defined document as if the server keeps reference to that document...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to get around this by serving up the HTML directly for each individual api. See below:

```js
// index.ts for X group of controllers

  const apiV1Html = swaggerUi.generateHTML(
    v1SwaggerDocument,
  );
  router.use(
    '/docs',
    swaggerUi.serveFiles(v1SwaggerDocument),
  );
  router.get('/docs', (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.send(apiV1Html);
  });
```

and for the Y group of controllers:

```js
// index.ts for y group of controllers

  const apiV2Html = swaggerUi.generateHTML(
    v2SwaggerDocument,
  );
  router.use(
    '/docs',
    swaggerUi.serveFiles(v2SwaggerDocument),
  );
  router.get('/docs', (req: any, res: any) => {
    res.send(apiV2Html);
  });
```

Sources: https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/issues/65