# use multiple api docs for swagger in node js?

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have given versioned my API for a project. so it has two folders v1 and v2  which has diffrent apis. Now in ordrer to implement swagger for v1 and v2 i have written below code in **app.js**.

```
// Swagger definition
// You can set every attribute except paths and swagger
const swaggerDefinition = {
    swagger: '2.0',
    info: {
        // API informations (required)
        title: 'API', // Title (required)
        version: '1.0.0', // Version (required)
        description: 'Used for  api documentation', // Description (optional)
    },
    host: `localhost:3000`, // Host (optional)
    basePath: '/v1', // Base path (optional)
};

// Options for the swagger docs
const optionsV1 = {
    // Import swaggerDefinitions
    swaggerDefinition,
    // Path to the API docs
    // Note that this path is relative to the current directory from which the Node.js is ran, not the application itself.
    apis: ['./app/v1/docs/*.yaml']
};

const optionsV2 = {
    // Import swaggerDefinitions
    swaggerDefinition,
    // Path to the API docs
    // Note that this path is relative to the current directory from which the Node.js is ran, not the application itself.
    apis: ['./app/v2/docs/*.yaml']
};
optionsV2.swaggerDefinition.basePath = "/v2"
// Initialize swagger-jsdoc -> returns validated swagger spec in json format
const swaggerSpecV1 = swaggerJSDoc(optionsV1);
const swaggerSpecV2 = swaggerJSDoc(optionsV2);
// const swaggerDocument = require('./app/v1/docs/swagger.json');
// app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDocument));
app.use('/v1/docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpecV1));
app.use('/v2/docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpecV2));
```

but the if i hit url as **/v1/docs** or **/v2/docs** it always show me the api doc for **v2**. so the last line written here for **v2** so it always showing doc for v2 only. Please suggests how to support multiple api?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger-ui-express module, instantiates only the last defined document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49607146/swagger-ui-express-module-instantiates-only-the-last-defined-document)

Comment: The CSS works fine for you on Swagger? I tried everything but the page served comes without styles.

Answer (score 5):

This is the Known issue in the Swagger UI.
Please use the following format to route the request:

```
var swaggerHtml = swaggerUi.generateHTML(swaggerDocument, swaggerUiOpts)
app.use('/api-docs-html1', swaggerUi.serveFiles(swaggerDocument, swaggerUiOpts))
app.get('/api-docs-html1', (req, res) => { res.send(swaggerHtml) });
```

Updated Code:

```
var swaggerHtmlV1 = swaggerUi.generateHTML(swaggerSpecV1, optionsV1)
var swaggerHtmlV2 = swaggerUi.generateHTML(swaggerSpecV2, optionsV2)

app.use('/v1/docs', swaggerUi.serveFiles(swaggerSpecV1, optionsV1))
app.get('/v1/docs', (req, res) => { res.send(swaggerHtmlV1) });

app.use('/v2/docs', swaggerUi.serveFiles(swaggerSpecV2, optionsV2))
app.get('/v2/docs', (req, res) => { res.send(swaggerHtmlV2) });
```

Please check the following link for more details:
https://github.com/scottie1984/swagger-ui-express/issues/65

Answer (score 3):

Try the following configuration:

```
app.use('/v1/docs', swaggerUi.serve, (...args) => swaggerUI.setup(swaggerSpecV1)(...args));
app.use('/v2/docs', swaggerUi.serve, (...args) => swaggerUI.setup(swaggerSpecV2)(...args));
```

Answer (score 2):

Converted my code as per answer

```
var swaggerHtmlV1 = swaggerUi.generateHTML(swaggerSpecV1, optionsV1)
var swaggerHtmlV2 = swaggerUi.generateHTML(swaggerSpecV2, optionsV2)

app.use('/v1/docs', swaggerUi.serveFiles(swaggerSpecV1, optionsV1))
app.get('/v1/docs', (req, res) => { res.send(swaggerHtmlV1) });

app.use('/v2/docs', swaggerUi.serveFiles(swaggerSpecV2, optionsV2))
app.get('/v2/docs', (req, res) => { res.send(swaggerHtmlV2) });
```